# app-ads.txt tab in AdMob not showing any apps Even though I've published two apps on Google Play

Tags: google-play, admob, app-ads.txt

My `app-ads.txt` tab in Admob console not showing anything Even though I've published two apps on Google Play. I've waited Weeks but no update.
Please help me as soon as possible, I am frustrated and I am very tired of searching a lot on the Internet about the problem and I did not find any solution or even a description similar to this strange problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem for some time now, app ads text file was not showing for one of my app in Admob, but for other apps it was visible.

**Solution:** Today, as I was checking the store settings of my app I realized that I was using a social media link in the place of website. I changed it immediately to my website.

After 10 minutes or so when I refreshed the Admob App Settings page, it found my app ads text file successfully.

Hope that helps!

[image: Google Console Store Settings]

Answer (score -2):

Only linked apps (Linked to a store) will appear in `app-ads.txt` tab in AdMob console.

This is how to link an app in AdMob to Google Play:

1. Go to AdMob console
2. Select the app you want to connect
3. Go to `app settings` from the left menu
4. Click on `ADD` from `App Store` section

[image: screenshot1]

5. Search for your app name and Add it

**IMPORTANT Note: you can not unlink your app later so PLEASE be careful and make sure that you are adding your app and not another app.**

6. now it may appear immediately in `app-ads.txt` tab in AdMob or it could take up to 48 hours

Comment: first thank you a lot for edited my Q and your help .. i linked two app from the begging !

Comment: If this is the case, then I think your apps is not available in all countries.

Comment: Also I've noticed that there is 0 active ads in both apps!

Comment: the apps are available in all country (176 country)

Comment: Also I've noticed that you didn't set up your app-ad.txt yet, please click on it and follow the steps.

Comment: i set up my app-ads.txt correctly by blogger website

Comment: I think you can't do this, blogger.com could only have one `app-ads.txt` for all of sub-domains. you need to buy your own domain and host `app-ads.txt`  on it.